# Правильно ли я рассчитала адрес следующей сети для IP адреса

Tags: сеть, ip, devops

Есть IP адрес `10.13.112.17 /16` со следующими атрибутами:

```
 - Netmask:     255.255.0.0     11111111.11111111 | 00000000.00000000
 - Network ID:  10.13.0.0       00001010.00001101 | 00000000.00000000
 - Broadcast IP:10.13.255.255   00001010.00001101 | 11111111.11111111
```

Нужно рассчитать IP адрес для следующей сети. Я cделала следующим образом:
к

```
00001010.00001101|00000000.00000000 (Network ID)  
+
00000000.00000001|00000000.00000000
=
00000000.00001110|00000000.00000000 (= 10.14.0.0.)
```

Всё ли верно я сделала???

Answer (score 1):

```
00001010.00001101|00000000.00000000 (Network ID)  
+
00000000.00000001|00000000.00000000
=
00001010.00001110|00000000.00000000 (= 10.14.0.0.)
```